# Render Problem with layout file and preview

Tags: android, material-design, android-appcompat

activity_login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Login">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
        android:text="LogIn"
        android:textColor="#641FE4"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    Material Button
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="123dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
        android:text="Go!"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:backgroundTint="#203377"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        app:cornerRadius="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.113"
        app:rippleColor="#03A9F4" />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the layout file. When I add another button it causes render problems. When I restart the studio it is not throwing errors but after build it throws an exception  java.lang.ClassCastException@b46a6ec

Comment: Can you show your xml file / class that uses the AppCompatButton?

Answer (score 0):

Check you have added material design library.

Comment: I have added the lib bro.